# Attached images only available on iOS simulator but not when tested on device

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I'm attempting to show an image from a file I have copied to my project in the folder "**Supporting Files**" > "**Images**" but the image links point to:     /Users/MyName/Documents/App Test/MyAppName.   That works fine in the iOS simulator but not when I test the app on my phone.  I'm quite new so my guess is it's simple.

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Wait are the images on your computer or in the app.  If you drag the images in make sure that you check the box that says `Copy Items into Destination Group's Folder`

Comment: Have you mentioned your image name correctly. Like whole name "image.png" must be same as the one in your project file. Possibly Check for caps in the images extension.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I can make the images work in the simulator but they don't show up when I run the app on my phone.  For some reason I cannot figure out how to link to the images in the app itself, the only link I can find references the files on my computer even though I chose to copy the items.  The items are in the group folder but the whole reference includes my computer which I think is the problem.  What would be the local link from within the app?  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]When copy any files, make sure you following things are checked
1. Destination[ y] copy items into destination group's folder 
2. Add to Target [y ]

Comment: Thanks for including that.  It's how I've been doing it.  I just added the note to the question above.  The images are in the folder, I just can't figure out what the path ought to be.

Comment: Delete the app installed in the phone and reinstall it

Comment: Thanks, That was the issue.  I just needed to reinstall the app with the updated sqlite file.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you haven't moved the image into your project. You're only pointing to the image's location on your Mac. The device (iphone, ipad) will not have access to your local assets. Make sure that `Copy items into destination group's folder` is checked when you try to transfer/add files to your project.

Comment: I made sure that was checked as well as Add to Target and that didn't help so I did it a second time with the same result.  I've been dragging into the Project Navigator, could that be the problem?

Comment: The same checkbox option appears under both scenarios. Make sure to check the box and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Adam, When I look at my image from the project navigator the "Full Path" remains: /Users/MyName/Documents/App Test/MyAppName.  What should my path actually be?  That's the part I can't figure out.  Thanks

Comment: To clarify I originally had image.jpg and /image.jpg but neither worked.

Comment: After a little more digging I have discovered that my images are in the destination group's folder because the "Full Path" of the images matches the full path of everything else.  Also under location, when "Relative to Group" is selected it's called image.jpg. Therefore, that's correct I am assuming. But if I provide image.jpg alone I get nothing, I also tried @"image.jpg" and still nothing.  What should my image path be?  Thanks